# Using Ctypes to wrap .LIB files

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I need to control a device in python using Ctypes. However, the libraries that come with the device are compiled .LIB files, not .DLLs. Is it still possible to use Ctypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not directly anyway. CTypes uses the dynamic linker (LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress) to work. You could wrap the LIB file in your own DLL possibly, but you won't be able to use Ctypes directly with the lib file.

Comment: How do I do that? I normally work with python, so while I know C++ syntax, I am not knowledgeable concerning output types from the compiler.

Comment: Depends on what your using (VS, mingw, msvc w/o VS, something else weird). Generally though this approach won't be hard, just tedious.